# What does all.equal do in R when it is executed on two matrices

Tags: r, matrix

What does all.equal do in R when it is executed on two matrices like bellow?
What is Mean relative difference and how is it calculated?

```
a <-
  matrix(c(4, 1, 1, 4),
         nrow = 2,
         dimnames = list(Guess = c("Milk", "Tea"),
                         Truth = c("Milk", "Tea")))
b <-
matrix(c(2, 3, 3, 2),
       nrow = 2,
       dimnames = list(Guess = c("Milk", "Tea"),
                       Truth = c("Milk", "Tea")))

all.equal(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For numeric input mean relative difference is calculated as absolute difference between both vectors as compared to first vector. So something like

```
mean(abs(a-b))/mean(abs(a))
#[1] 0.8
```

Comment: This solved my question, but what does the output tells us (what is the interpretation of it?)? When is the difference to big for example?

Comment: @jenniferruurs Try running on different examples. See `all.equal(10, 2000)` which is `abs(10-2000)/10` and some similar examples.

Answer (score -1):

This is a weird behavior. "Istruing" all equal would produce expected output (FALSE).
Sorry if I'm not really answering the question.

```
a <-
  matrix(c(4, 1, 1, 4),
         nrow = 2,
         dimnames = list(Guess = c("Milk", "Tea"),
                         Truth = c("Milk", "Tea")))
b <-
  matrix(c(2, 3, 3, 2),
         nrow = 2,
         dimnames = list(Guess = c("Milk", "Tea"),
                         Truth = c("Milk", "Tea")))

isTRUE(all.equal(a, b))

a <-
  matrix(c(4, 1, 1, 4),
         nrow = 2,
         dimnames = list(Guess = c("Milk", "Tea"),
                         Truth = c("Milk", "Tea")))
b <-
  matrix(c(4, 1, 1, 4),
         nrow = 2,
         dimnames = list(Guess = c("Milk", "Tea"),
                         Truth = c("Milk", "Tea")))

isTRUE(all.equal(a, b))
```